# Why does seaborn render the same graph over and over in facet grid?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have the following `pandas` dataframe:

```
Degree Entry_Year  Graduations  Non_Graduations  Graduation_Rate
0   AUDIT       2007          0.0              1.0         0.000000
1   AUDIT       2008          0.0              7.0         0.000000
2   AUDIT       2009          0.0              4.0         0.000000
3   AUDIT       2015          0.0              1.0         0.000000
4    CERT       2009          1.0              1.0        50.000000
5    CERT       2010          4.0              6.0        40.000000
6    CERT       2011          2.0              5.0        28.571429
7    CERT       2012          1.0              6.0        14.285714
8    CERT       2013          3.0              5.0        37.500000
9    CERT       2014          5.0              7.0        41.666667
10   CERT       2015          2.0              5.0        28.571429
11   CERT       2016          0.0              4.0         0.000000
12   CERT       2017          0.0              1.0         0.000000
13    COM       2007          0.0             15.0         0.000000
14    COM       2008          0.0             16.0         0.000000
15    COM       2009          0.0              7.0         0.000000
16     CR       2012          0.0              2.0         0.000000
17   DMIN       2007          2.0              3.0        40.000000
18     MA       2007          3.0              8.0        27.272727
19     MA       2008          3.0              4.0        42.857143
20     MA       2009          1.0              8.0        11.111111
21     MA       2010          4.0              3.0        57.142857
22     MA       2011          2.0              8.0        20.000000
23     MA       2012          8.0             10.0        44.444444
24     MA       2013          1.0              0.0       100.000000
25     MA       2014          0.0              2.0         0.000000
26     MA       2015          1.0              2.0        33.333333
27  MAPSC       2010          8.0              2.0        80.000000
28  MAPSC       2011          9.0             10.0        47.368421
29  MAPSC       2012          5.0              9.0        35.714286
..    ...        ...          ...              ...              ...
61    MTS       2008          2.0              4.0        33.333333
62    MTS       2009          4.0              5.0        44.444444
63    MTS       2010          5.0              7.0        41.666667
64    MTS       2011          1.0              5.0        16.666667
65    MTS       2012          4.0              5.0        44.444444
66    MTS       2013          8.0              8.0        50.000000
67    MTS       2014          1.0              5.0        16.666667
68    MTS       2015          5.0             19.0        20.833333
69    MTS       2016          0.0             19.0         0.000000
70    MTS       2017          0.0              6.0         0.000000
```

When I run the following code to plot this data as a facet grid, however, the grid merely prints the same graph over and over again. Here is the code I am using:

```
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

sns.set(font_scale=1)
plot = sns.FacetGrid(df, col='Degree', col_wrap=6, despine=True)
plot = plot.map(sns.barplot, x='Entry_Year', y='Graduation_Rate', data=df, ci=None)
plot.set_xticklabels(rotation=45)
plot.fig.tight_layout(w_pad=1)
plt.show(plot)
```

And here is the result I get:

[test_result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjyVx.png)

Does anyone know why seaborn does not use the `Degree` column to construct different plots for each facet? (I'm about to set out on my commute but will check back in in an hour or so.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `data` argument inside `plot.map()`, and make the keyword args positional - that should do it.  Here's some sample data that roughly reproduces your use case:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

start_date = '1995'
drange = pd.date_range(start_date, periods=20, freq='A').strftime('%Y')
possible_groups = ['AUDIT','CERT','COM']
groups = np.random.choice(possible_groups, len(drange), replace=True)
values = np.random.randint(0, 100, len(drange))

df = pd.DataFrame({'Entry_Year':drange, 'Degree':groups, 'Graduation_Rate':values})

sns.set(font_scale=1)
plot = sns.FacetGrid(df, col='Degree', col_wrap=6, despine=True)
plot = plot.map(sns.barplot, 'Entry_Year', 'Graduation_Rate', ci=None)
plot.set_xticklabels(rotation=45)
plot.fig.tight_layout(w_pad=1)
plt.show(plot)
```

[image: facet grid]

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks a million!